# How to output the predicted value(label) in tensorflow MNIST tutorial?

Tags: graph, machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow, deep-learning

In tensorflow's tutorial of MNIST, the last step is to output the test accuracy of the model using the following code:

```
# Test trained model
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images,
                                  y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

However, I was wondering how can I modify this code to output the predicted value(label) of the test set, instead of just printing out the accuracy?

Here's the link of the tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/mnist/beginners/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
print(sess.run(tf.argmax(y, 1), feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images}))
```

Because `y` in tutorial is tensor where column with index `j` describes how likely image in row `i` is number `j`, so `tf.argmax` just returns index of column with highest probability for each row.

PS Sorry for my English

Comment: I change your code into:

print sess.run(tf.argmax(y, 1), feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images})

and it works. Thanks a lot!